# Sharpening and Enhancing a 3D Scan Object's Detail

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects

A Blender newbie here.

I have an object that was scanned which has some raised details.

How can I enhance those details?  I am looking to sharpen the edges and raise the various levels to make then more clear when printing. The goal is to make the details really pop and be more obvious then they are now.

[image: This is the detail I want to enhance.]  [image: Another view showing a bit of depth that I want to increase.]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use brushes like *Crease* in order to sharpen the cavities, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to sharpen the crests:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Let me learn about that :-) and give it a try!